# push Notification not working in ios ionic using FCM

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

i have setup all the steps for push notification using https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#access_the_registration_token but i didn't get notification in ios App but working in Android App and also with http://pushtry.com .how to resolve this issue

Comment: its urgent can any one help me out

Comment: Have you uploaded P12 Certificate on FCM.?

Comment: yes i have uploaded the certificate on fcm

Comment: which mode you are using.. development or Production mode?

Comment: development mode

Comment: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox  OR FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeProd.      in Appdelegate.m file?

Comment: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenTypeSandbox

Comment: @ Varinder Singh  i don't know much about Appdelegate.m because i used   ionic

Comment: See Enable push notification in info.Plist Que —  https://stackoverflow.com/q/37458530/4970453
And check Ans——  https://stackoverflow.com/a/39227289/4970453

Comment: i have enabled push notification in info.plist file it working when i use pushtry.com but not with my backend

Comment: using Google FCM tester or iOS APN tester ? in pushtry.com

Comment: i have used iOS APN tester

Comment: FCM device token is Diffrent from APNDevice token. maybe your device token is wrong. FCM Ios Token is 150+ character ,APN token is just 64 bit

Comment: my token is this 05f81c77efce6c079fc0a92cdea69ddc5c161c8ae8b5f87257c6cac2adce5f37

Comment: its APN token not FCM token.. which plugin you are using.? Have a look on https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153787/discussion-between-suniel-kalwani-and-varinder-singh).

Comment: i have used phonegap-plugin-push

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and after searching for a day here are my conclusions:

1. Don't forget to allow for push notification in your App ID.Click on edit and then enable push notification.
2. Make sure your certificates you are using are correct because as you allow for push notification your previous profiles become invalid(In my case they were).So either edit the provision profiles and download again or create new ones.

   3.I'll prefer using `Apn-auth` key as suggested on main firebase site instead of `apns` certificates.

> 4.One of the major point which I was missing was  the problem with `xcode` [Enable push notification there in the `xcode` as well which
>   are not enabled by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html).

5. If your app is closing soon after opening your plist might be the cause [Follow this answer for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47673560/6517383) .

> 6. Last thing that really helped me fix the issue was a mac OS update.I was trying to build using xcode 7.2 which was quiet dumb part on my
>      side.There when I tried to enable push notification.It made changes to
>      my certificates and then I downloaded the provisional profile after
>      editing them(So valid now) and then build and everything started
>      working fine as hell.

Comment: can we use Apn-auth key for both development and production mode ?

Comment: Yes I think they're the same for both production and dev

Comment: but its not working in production mode . so what i can do now?

Comment: i am getting NotRegistered Error